Using RPATH on nested list in SQL in QueryRecord in NiFi
I have a json
[
  {
    "orderId": "100",
    "orderItems": [
      {
        "orderItemSeqId": "101",
        "externalId": "56789"
      },
      {
        "orderItemSeqId": "102",
        "externalId": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": "200",
    "orderItems": [
      {
        "orderItemSeqId": "201",
        "externalId": "78990"
      },
      {
        "orderItemSeqId": "202",
        "externalId": "83937"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Using QueryRecord processor in NiFi, I wish to select the orders having any item with null externalId.
So, in the output we should have only the first map with "100" orderId as it has one item with null externalId.
I tried this SQL with RPATH but doesn't work:
SELECT * 
FROM flowfile 
WHERE RPATH_STRING(orderItems, '[*][isEmpty(./externalId)]')  = 'true'

isEmpty function of RecordPath returns true if the string is empty or null else false.

but doesn't work - this is a complaint whereas we'd see techincal information (error message, for example). From the other side - MySQL does not know that some NiFi exists, and that it implements some isEmpty function... and in general, why is the question tagged with [mysql]? Do you use it?
